# CPU overheating during gaming after overclock

Tags: cpu, cooling, overheating

I recently installed a Thermalake Frio CPU cooler to overclock my intel i5 2500K.
I followed a guide on how to do it, overclocked it to 4.1 ghz and upped the voltage a little (one lower than the 'orange' digits). 
When I restarted my pc everything was normal, temperatures were okay. However, when I start Guild Wars 2, it heats up to +- 95 °C. When I close the game, it goes back to 40-50°C within seconds, so the cooler is working (and it's running, I checked it).
I changed the voltage back to 'AUTO' in the BIOS, but nothing changed.
I turned it down to 3.8 ghz and the temperatures, during gaming, only reached 85 °C, still too high.

Now the whole point of installing the cooler was to overclock it to +- 4 ghz, so how do I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `One Size That Fits All` when it comes to overclocking. Your chip may not need as much voltage as a certain guide suggests. The required voltage is greatly dependent on what general computer enthusiasts refer to as the `Silicone Lottery` i.e. some chips will be better overclockers than others.

You can by all means look at an overclocking guide, but it's generally advisable to increase the voltage in very small steps (e.g. 0.005) and test after each increase. To test, I use a combination of benchmarking software, including, but not limited to `Prime95`, `Intel Burn Test`, `OCCT` and even `Folding@Home`. You don't have to use all of them, but I've found some inconsistencies with reported stability when using just a single benchmarking test.

Your temperature issue may be down to how you applied the thermal paste, how the cooler has been mounted or you simply using too high of a voltage. Each `CPU` has a limit in terms of how much voltage you can push through it and you might be at the point where you are pushing its limits. The `AUTO` voltage setting usually uses a higher than required voltage, which is why it is not normally recommended to keep the voltage setting on normal, if you're worried about getting the best temperatures.

You should remove the cooler, clean the thermal paste, apply a fresh batch and then re-mount the cooler. When you install the cooler, tighten the screws in a cross pattern (`top-right` screw, `bottom-left` screw, `top-left` screw and then the `bottom-right` screw). This will ensure that even pressure is applied and will allow the thermal paste to spread evenly.

When you apply thermal paste, less is more. The contact between the `CPU` and the `Cooler Heatsink` only needs a very thin layer of thermal paste in order to transfer the heat efficiently. I usually use a small pea/grain of rice sized blob. In your case the contact between the cooler and your CPU may contain air-bubbles or the thermal paste may be too excessive, which is causing the massive spike in temperature. Whenever you remove the `Heatsink`, you should always apply a fresh layer of thermal paste.

It's a lengthy process, but its all about trial and error. If you're still not happy with the temperatures after doing the above, you could try setting a custom fan profile using `Third-Party Software` or through the `BIOS`.

Comment: :) Let us know how it goes

Comment: No probs :). Great to hear